How can I run Github workflow job manually?
In Gitlab and Bitbucket, we can add manual step in pipeline. is there any way we can do same thing in a Github action?
#.gitlab-ci.yml
destroy:
  stage: destroy
  script:
    - [STEPS TO DESTROY]
  when: manual

I want to run the integration-test job manually when creating a pull request targeting master, main and develop branch.  The job static-code-analysis job should run automatically when creating a pull request targeting master, release\*, develop or main.
#ci.yml
name: Pull Request

on:
  pull_request:
    branches:
      - master
      - release*
      - develop
      - main
  workflow_dispatch:

jobs:
  static-code-analysis:
    runs-on: macos-latest
    env:
      SLACK_WEBHOOK_URL: ${{ secrets.SLACK_WEBHOOK_URL }}
    steps:    
      - name: Checkout code
        id: Checkout-code
        uses: actions/checkout@v3

      - name: Notify Slack
        uses: act10ns/slack@v2
        with:
          channel: 's1-panel'
          status: ${{ job.status }}
          steps: ${{ toJson(steps) }}
        if: always()

  integration-test:
    if: ${{ github.event_name == 'workflow_dispatch' && (github.base_ref == 'main' || github.base_ref == 'master' || github.base_ref == 'develop') }}
    runs-on: macos-latest
    permissions: write-all
    env:
      SLACK_WEBHOOK_URL: ${{ secrets.SLACK_WEBHOOK_URL }}
    steps:
      - name: Checkout code
        id: Checkout-code
        uses: actions/checkout@v3

      - name: Notify Slack 
        uses: act10ns/slack@v2
        with:
          channel: 's1-panel'
          status: ${{ job.status }}
          steps: ${{ toJson(steps) }}
        if: always()

I have tried using an if statement in the integration-test job as below:
if: ${{ github.event_name == 'workflow_dispatch' && (github.base_ref == 'main' || github.base_ref == 'master' || github.base_ref == 'develop') }}

I created a pull request from branch testing to master. The workflow started and when I go to Github workflow and see integration-test job, it looks like this:


The github.based_ref property is only available on pull requests, not when the job was manually started via the a workflow_dispatch event. For general hints, check https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/manually-running-a-workflow. Now, the question remains: when (and how) exactly do you want to start the job?


Configure pull_request trigger with the base branches
 on:
   pull_request:
     types: [created]
     branches: [main,master,develop]


Add environment to the job (no need to use if:)
 integration-test:
   runs-on: macos-latest
   permissions: write-all
   environment: manual
   env:
     SLACK_WEBHOOK_URL: ${{ secrets.SLACK_WEBHOOK_URL }}
   steps:


Create an environment 'manual' on the repo with deployment protection rule that requires manual approval.

On PR creation, job static-code-analysis will run automatically. Job integration-test will block, waiting for manual approval. A prompt will appear on the workflow run UI to give your approval.

Environments are free on public repos, private repos need a Team or Pro plan.



while my integration step is in the waiting stat, does it count toward the build minutes? is this waiting state in count under waiting minutes?

No, the workflow is not consuming any resources while waiting for an environment approval. Only running jobs  consume runner resources.
